# Swagger UI doesn't show my APIs when using paths regex

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, springfox

I hava a problem with swagger UI. When I use paths regex in my swagger configuration class, this doesn't find my APIs. When I use the value PathsSelectors.any() this find my APIs but show also my models. I should show only my API so I have decided to use the regex.

This is my Swagger config:

```
package com.my.project.configurations;


@org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:application.properties")
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Configuration implements WebMvcConfigurer {
@Override
public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
    registry.addMapping("/**").allowedMethods("*");
}

@Bean
public Docket productApi(){
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .select()
            .apis(
                    withClassAnnotation(RestController.class)
                            .and(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.my.project.controller"))
            )
            .paths(regex("/rest.*"))
            .build();
}
```

this is my Main:

```
package com.my.project;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@SpringBootApplication ( exclude = {SecurityAutoConfiguration.class} )
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.my.project.repository")
@EntityScan(basePackages= {"com.my.project.entities"})
public class MyProjectApplication {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(MyProjectApplication.class, args);
 }

}
```

this is my restcontroller:

```
package com.my.project.controller;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/rest/pattern")
public class PatternController {

@Autowired
private IPattern patternSvc;

@GetMapping(value = { "/get-all-pattern" }, produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
@ApiOperation(value = "get all pattern", tags = "pattern")
public ResponseEntity<BaseAjaxResponse<List<PatternDto>>> findAllPattern(){

    HttpStatus status = HttpStatus.OK;
    BaseAjaxResponse.BaseAjaxResponseBuilder<List<PatternDto>> builder = BaseAjaxResponse.<List<PatternDto>>builder();

    try{
        List<PatternDto> listPattern = this.patternSvc.findAllPattern();

        if(!listPattern.isEmpty()){
            builder
                    .description("Success")
                    .size(listPattern.size())
                    .code(status.value())
                    .payload(listPattern);
        }
        else{
            builder
                    .description("Hidden list")
                    .code(status.value())
                    .size(0);
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        status = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;

        builder
                .description("No patterns found")
                .size(0)
                .code(status.value())
                .errors(ApiError.builder()
                        .error(MyProjectInternalError.GENERIC_ERROR.keySet().toArray()[0].toString())
                        .datails(Collections.singletonList(
                                ErrorDetail
                                        .builder()
                                        .code(String.valueOf(MyProjectInternalError.GENERIC_ERROR.get("GENERIC ERROR")))
                                        .field("generic")
                                        .message(e.getMessage())
                                        .build()
                        ))
                        .build());
    }
    return ResponseEntity.status(status).body(builder.build());
 }

}
```

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I solved adding .ignoredParameterTypes(MyClass1.class, Myclass2.class, ...)
to my Docket bean and setting paths with PathSelectors.any() value